# Por qué el null?

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando ***crear un div con texto dentro de él desde Javascript***, pero me da el error `'null'` y ***no entiendo cual es el error del código***.

```js
/* Playing with DOM */
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    document.body.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: grey;');
    var mainDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
    mainDiv.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: white; width: 200px; height: 200px; position: absolute; border: 2px solid red;');
    mainDiv.setAttribute('id', 'main');
    var mainText = document.createElement("H4");
    var iText = document.createTextNode("Coma flotante");
    var mainTextB = document.createElement("B");
    var iTextB = document.createTextNode("Estoy aprendiendo a usar el DOM y además las comas flotantes. 4 * 0.2 es equivalente a 4 * .2");
    mainTextB.appendChild(iTextB);
    var geta = document.getElementById('main');
    var ultimo = geta.childNodes[0]; // <-- ERROR !
    ultimo.parentNode.insertBefore(ultimo, mainTextB);
    mainText.setAttribute('style', 'text-align: center; text-decoration: underline');
    mainText.appendChild(iText);
    mainDiv.appendChild(mainText);
    document.body.appendChild(mainDiv);
    /*mainDiv.addEventListener("click", function () {

        doV('dos', '300', '300', 'red', 'Textualizado');
    });*/

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
<script src="main.js"></script>
<head>
    <title>Eduardo Sebastián</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Con hacer `mainDiv.childNodes` te valdría porque tu `geta` quieres que tenga el valor de `mainDiv`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes varios problemas. El primero, como dice @Asier es que has creado el `div` pero no lo has añadido al documento (resumiendo su buena explicacion).
Eso se arreglaría de la siguiente manera

```
document.body.appendChild(mainDiv);//<- Asi añades el mainDiv al HTML
var geta = document.getElementById('main');
var ultimo = geta.childNodes[0];
```

El siguiente problema te lo encuentras en la siguiente linea

```
ultimo.parentNode.insertBefore(ultimo, mainTextB);
```

Esto es porque tampoco has añadido ningún hijo al `mainDiv`, por lo que `geta.childNodes[0];` es `undefined`.

Esto lo arreglas en el momento que creas el primer texto, tienes que añadir el texto a su nodo, y el nodo a el `mainDiv`

```
var mainText = document.createElement("H4");
var iText = document.createTextNode("Coma flotante");
mainText.appendChild(iText);
mainDiv.appendChild(mainText);
```

Despues de esto se te presentara el siguiente error

> Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.

Eso es porque estas intentando añadir `ultimo` despues de `mainTextB`,dado que `mainTextB` todavia no ha sido añadido al documento te da error.

Para solucionar esto simplemente cambia el orden del `insertBefore`:

```
ultimo.parentNode.insertBefore(mainTextB,ultimo);
```

Te dejo el script completo para que puedas seguir con tus pruebas.

```js
/* Playing with DOM */
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    document.body.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: grey;');
    var mainDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
    mainDiv.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: white; width: 200px; height: 200px; position: absolute; border: 2px solid red;');
    mainDiv.setAttribute('id', 'main');
    var mainText = document.createElement("H4");
    var iText = document.createTextNode("Coma flotante");
    mainText.appendChild(iText);
    mainDiv.appendChild(mainText);
    
    
    var mainTextB = document.createElement("B");
    var iTextB = document.createTextNode("Estoy aprendiendo a usar el DOM y además las comas flotantes. 4 * 0.2 es equivalente a 4 * .2");
    mainTextB.appendChild(iTextB);    
    document.body.appendChild(mainDiv);//<- Asi añades el mainDiv al HTML
    var geta = document.getElementById('main');
    var ultimo = geta.childNodes[0]; // <-- ERROR !
    ultimo.parentNode.insertBefore(mainTextB,ultimo);
    
    mainText.setAttribute('style', 'text-align: center; text-decoration: underline');
    mainText.appendChild(iText);
    mainDiv.appendChild(mainText);
    document.body.appendChild(mainDiv);
    /*mainDiv.addEventListener("click", function () {

        doV('dos', '300', '300', 'red', 'Textualizado');
    });*/

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
<script src="main.js"></script>
<head>
    <title>Eduardo Sebastián</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: me podrías explicar un poco mejor , porqué lo del cambio? funciona pero no entendí mucho eso

Comment: @EduardoSebastian que cambio quieres que te explique exactamente?

Comment: En el orden del insertBefore

Comment: @EduardoSebastian es cosa del metodo de JavaScript, aqui puedes verlo https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_insertbefore.asp. En el ´insertBefore´ el primer parametro que usas es el elemento que añades, y el segundo el elemento al que estas añadiendo.

Answer (score 2):

El problema está en las instrucciones:

```
var geta = document.getElementById('main');
var ultimo = geta.childNodes[0]; // <-- ERROR !**texto en negrita**
```

En la variable `geta` tratas de almacenar el elemento con `id = 'main'` del `document`. Pero este no existe. Sí has creado un `div` con `id` 'main' en la variable `mainDiv` pero no has añadido este elemento al `document` y, por tanto, no existe dentro de éste.

Luego cuando intentas obtener el primer hijo del elemento contenido en la variable `geta` (que no es ninguno, dado que la búsqueda anterior no ha devuelto ningún resultado) te genera el error.

Answer (score 1):

El problema esta en que intentando hacer una consulta de un elemento que aunque ya creaste no le has insertado en el DOM, ademas tienes un error en la implementación del `insertBefore`, en todo caso tu fallo es en el orden de las cosas.

```js
/* Playing with DOM */
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    document.body.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: grey;');
    var mainDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
    mainDiv.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: white; width: 200px; height: 200px; position: absolute; border: 2px solid red;');
    mainDiv.setAttribute('id', 'main');
    var mainText = document.createElement("H4");
    var iText = document.createTextNode("Coma flotante");
    var mainTextB = document.createElement("B");
    var iTextB = document.createTextNode("Estoy aprendiendo a usar el DOM y además las comas flotantes. 4 * 0.2 es equivalente a 4 * .2");
    /** Primero es necesario agregar los elementos creador al DOM*/
    document.body.appendChild(mainDiv);
    mainDiv.appendChild(mainText);
    mainText.setAttribute('style', 'text-align: center; text-decoration: underline');
    mainText.appendChild(iText);
    mainTextB.appendChild(iTextB); 
    /** getElementaryById(...) buscara los elementos existentes en el DOM **/
    var geta = document.getElementById('main');  
    var ultimo = geta.childNodes[0]; 
    /** Aqui habia una mala implentación del insertBefore */
    ultimo.parentNode.insertBefore(mainTextB, ultimo);
    
    /*mainDiv.addEventListener("click", function () {
        doV('dos', '300', '300', 'red', 'Textualizado');
    });*/
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
<script src="main.js"></script>
<head>
    <title>Eduardo Sebastián</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```